# Mysql combine 2 column vertically (not asking for concat)

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with 2 cols:

```
category count
x0         10
x1         20
x2         30
x3         40
```

I want to combine `category` `x1` and `x3` to be named `x1` and the corresponding `count` value to be the sum `(20 +40 =60)`

the desired result is as follows :

```
category count
x0         10
x1         60
x2         30
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
UPDATE `table` 
SET `count` = ( SELECT * 
                FROM ( SELECT SUM(`count`) 
                       FROM `table` 
                       WHERE `category` IN ('x1','x3') 
                     ) x
              ) 
WHERE `category` = 'x1';

DELETE FROM `table` 
WHERE `category` = 'x3';
```

#### [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0a566/2)

Comment: I want to permanently change the table to be the new table tho, will this work?

Comment: @jenn : Have you achieved the desired result ?

Comment: what does the x in "IN ('x1','x3'))x)" mean from your code?

Comment: @jenn : it is an alias for a temporary table as in mysql you can't specify a permanent table in the `WHERE` clause while updating it. You can use the alias you want, `x` is just an example.

Comment: @shmosel : Yep, I have not decided to put or not to put `DELETE` here, but your comment pointed out the right action)

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT IF(category = 'x3', 'x1', category) AS adjusted_category
     , SUM(count) AS `count` 
FROM ... 
GROUP BY adjusted_category
```

**EDIT:** Fixed.

Comment: If he's looking for an update for this specific scenario, the whole question seems a little pointless. Why not just do `UPDATE ... SET count = 60 WHERE category = 'x1'; DELETE FROM ... WHERE category = 'x3';`